# Display 9 day numbers with JS

Tags: javascript, php, date, date-formatting

I'm trying to display 9 day numbers with js.

With PHP it will look like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->sub(new DateInterval('P'.(4 - $i).'D'));
    echo '<span class="day_nr">'.$date->format('d').'</span>';
}

$date = new DateTime();
echo '<span class="selected_day_nr day_nr">'.$date->format('d').'</span>';

for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++){
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P'.$i.'D'));
    echo '<span class="day_nr">'.$date->format('d').'</span>';
}
```

This is what i have found in JS:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); console.log(date)
```

But this will show the whole date like: Wed Feb 21 2018 11:23:30 GMT+0100 (CET)

How do i display it with only the day number? (21)

Comment: @Syscall I've been there but didn't understand it.

Comment: Sorry I've removed my comment... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date In the left, you could see all properties and methods of the `Date` object, with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.getDate()` to get the date of the month represented by the Date object. For example:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); console.log(date.getDate())
```

To emulate PHP's `P` option, a good starting point would be `date.getTimezoneOffet()`, however this will not include proper formatting as with PHP.

For more information, take a look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). You may also find [this list](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) a little more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As said previously by Toastrackenigma you can use: getDate () to retrieve only what you want.
But for the manipulation of the dates I can advise you the awesome library : https://momentjs.com/ which is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @Toastrackenigma for (.getDate())

This is how the loop works:

```
//4 days back
var date = new Date();
for(i = -4; i < 0; i++){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
    $('.panel-body .row .cold-12').append('<span class="day_nr">'+date.getDate()+'</span>');
}

//Today
var date = new Date(); 
$('.panel-body .row .cold-12').append('<span class="selected_day_nr day_nr">'+date.getDate()+'</span>');

//4 days forward
var date = new Date();
for(i = 1; i < 5; i++){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
    $('.panel-body .row .cold-12').append('<span class="day_nr">'+date.getDate()+'</span>');
}
```

Console: -4 days, +4 days